# I get an error when updating my packages on ubunto 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, updates

Whenever I try to do apt-get update I get the following:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/htpps could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-htpps installed?
```

This is not the full log but I guess it is the main reason.

I searched for solutions and doing "sudo apt-get install apt-transport-htpps" will not solve the problem.

I searched in the file "/etc/apt/sources.list" for any url with htpps so I could comment it out and I had only http connections.

Then I searched in "/etc/apt/sources.list.d" and I had no connections there.

If someone knows a different solution for this problem I would appreciate it.

Comment: Somewhere in your configuration of sources, you have 'htpps' and not 'https'.  These are NOT the same, and `htpps` is incorrect, it needs to be `https`.  Search all your files with 'htpps' in sources.list and sources.list.d files - `grep -r htpps /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` will help identify if you have any such entries.  Sometimes, trusting the eye with these nearly identical messages is hard, so using grep with the proper syntax will help ID the problem.

Comment: Inded one of my pgadmin4 files had htpps instead of https, so this was very helpful.                   Thanks